# Apache File Upload Exception while uploading files greater than 2 MB

Tags: apache, tomcat, file-upload, gwtupload

I get the following exception while uploading a file using gwt upload, while everything works fine while uploading a small file <2MB this error occurs when I try to upload a file of > 2MB file

```
2014-02-07 01:40:55 UploadServlet [INFO] UPLOAD-SERVLET init: maxSize=26214400, slowUploads=0, isAppEngine=false
2014-02-07 01:40:55 UploadListener [INFO] UploadListener  created new instance. (slow=0, requestSize=13573900)
2014-02-07 01:41:58 UploadServlet [ERROR] UPLOAD-SERVLET (7B84E73710BCF20B106DE08C644D0EF3.qtc02) Unexpected Exception -> Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Socket read failed
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Socket read failed
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:371)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
        at gwtupload.server.UploadServlet.parsePostRequest(UploadServlet.java:796)
        at gwtupload.server.UploadAction.doPost(UploadAction.java:159)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2419)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Socket read failed
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.read(AjpAprProcessor.java:328)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.readMessage(AjpAprProcessor.java:424)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.receive(AjpAprProcessor.java:383)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.refillReadBuffer(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:657)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:1135)
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:449)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:315)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:976)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:886)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:96)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:66)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:366)
        ... 25 more
```

This is the configuration of my server.xml file

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true"
scheme="https" secure="true" connectionTimeout="40000" connectionUploadTimeout="36000000" disableUploadTimeout="false" bufferSize="4096" acceptCount="250" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
                                                                    />

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" secure="true" executor="tomcatThreadPool"
enableLookups="false" acceptCount="250" connectionTimeout="40000"                                               packetSize="21000" redirectPort="8443" bufferSize="4096"                                                                    />
```

My web.xml upload parameter is :-

```
<context-param>
    <!-- max size of the upload request -->
    <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
    <param-value>26214400</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Is this problem solved? I'm facing similar problem! @Caadi0

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add this to your web.xml. The size is in octets

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
        <param-value>100000</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already do that, and the size that I have set is 26214400, which is way above 2MBs. I guess I should have mentioned that in my question.